# I need to access a variable in .run() module in angular and need to change the value of it in different controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'Session', function ($rootScope, $state, Session) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState) {
        console.log('inside .run')
        if (toState.url == '/') {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (Session.user) { // and isAdmin == true
                $state.go('admin')
             }  //if isAdmin == false redirect to chat

            else {
                $state.go('login')
            }
        } else if (!Session.user && toState.url != '/login') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login')
        }    

        return;
    });
}])
```

This is my .run module and in that i need to initialize a `isAdmin` variable  which i can change in my controllers and check if `isAdmin is`true in every state change and redirect to `admin` or `chat` page.
i tried adding initializing `isAdmin` as `$rootScope.isAdmin` in `.run()` but before i can fix its value in controller the `.run()` throws `isAdmin` undefined error.
Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to call service?

Comment: That is really very helpful to get value in each controller

Comment: ui-state have 4 events before controller loads you must check whether that variable have value set or not

Comment: Use `typeof isAdmin == 'undefined'` to check if is undefined and then do the appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

Review below code it may accessible scope variables.Inject a service is an idle way to access variables and methods which are reusable in variable palces.

> MyCtrl.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    function MyCtrl($rootScope, $scope, MyService) {
        MyService.getRootScopeData();
        MyService.setRootScopeData('How are you?');
    }
    angular
            .module("AppRootTest")
            .controller('MyCtrl', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "MyService", MyCtrl]);
}());
```

> MyService.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    function MyService($rootScope) {
        function getRootScopeData() {
            console.log("$rootScope.getRooScopeData");
            console.log($rootScope.someData);
            return $rootScope.someData;
        }
        function setRootScopeData(value_) {
            $rootScope.someData = {message: value_};
        }
        return ({
            getRootScopeData: getRootScopeData,
            setRootScopeData: setRootScopeData
        });
    }
    angular
            .module("AppRootTest")
            .service("HzPopupService", ['$rootScope', MyService])
}());
```

> app.js

```
angular.
    module('AppRootTest', ['ngResource','ngCookies','ngRoute','ui.router',])
    .config()
    .run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.someData = {message: "hello"};
    }]);
```